# Skipping the first record of each group in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, spring-data, mongotemplate

Consider a Entity: Employee having fields *name, department*.

*Database*: MongoDB

I want to find all records from the Database such that: Group all employees by department, each group's records will be sorted in descending order of name and skip the **first record from each group**.

Consider the DB had these records:

| Name | department |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | D1 |
| Name2 | D2 |
| Name3 | D1 |
| Name4 | D1 |
| Name5 | D2 |
| Name6 | D2 |
| Name7 | D1 |
| Name8 | D1 |

JSON Format-

```
{{name: "Name1", department:"D1" },
{name: "Name2", department:"D2" },
{name: "Name3", department:"D1" },
{name: "Name4", department:"D1" },
{name: "Name5", department:"D2" },
{name: "Name6", department:"D2" },
{name: "Name7", department:"D1" },
{name: "Name8", department:"D1" }}
```

Then after grouping the records by department and sorting each group by name (descending), intermediate result will be:

| Name | department |
| --- | --- |
| Name8 | D1 |
| Name7 | D1 |
| Name4 | D1 |
| Name3 | D1 |
| Name1 | D1 |
| Name6 | D2 |
| Name5 | D2 |
| Name2 | D2 |

JSON Format:

```
{{name: "Name8", department:"D1" },
{name: "Name7", department:"D1" },
{name: "Name4", department:"D1" },
{name: "Name3", department:"D1" },
{name: "Name1", department:"D1" },
{name: "Name6", department:"D2" },
{name: "Name5", department:"D2" },
{name: "Name2", department:"D2" }}
```

Now, **skipping the first record of each group** and hence FINAL output should be:

| Name | department |
| --- | --- |
| Name7 | D1 |
| Name4 | D1 |
| Name3 | D1 |
| Name1 | D1 |
| Name5 | D2 |
| Name2 | D2 |

JSON Format:

```
{
{name: "Name7", department:"D1" },
{name: "Name4", department:"D1" },
{name: "Name3", department:"D1" },
{name: "Name1", department:"D1" },
{name: "Name5", department:"D2" },
{name: "Name2", department:"D2" }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Can this be achieved using a single query to mongodb? If yes then what should be the query.
2. How it can be achieved using Spring Data: Aggregation?

Note: I want to remove the found documents from the DB, so I am using the mongoTemplate.findAllAndRemove(), in which I will send the query, hence it's preferable if it's also explained how to frame the query accordingly so I can pass that to this method.

I have already tried using the Spring Data MongoDB aggregations, but unable to skip the first record of each group.

Comment: Please provide sample data as JSON text. You can use `$setWindowFields`. Based on `$documentNumber` you can filter on `$gt: 1`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit can you please provide a example, it will help me frame the query. Also, now I've provided the sample data as JSON text too.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue about spring, but the aggregation pipeline would be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $setWindowFields: {
         partitionBy: "$department",
         sortBy: { name: -1 },
         output: {
            position: { $documentNumber: {} }
         }
      }
   },
   { $match: { position: { $gt: 1 } } },
   { $unset: "position" }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HVh_9QgtXS5)